# Python - Key not found in JSON data, how to parse other elements?

Tags: python, json, facebook

I have data from a Facebook group feed (24000 odd records in total). Eg.

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "message": "MoneyWise its time to vote for the 2017 winners https://www.moneywise.co.uk/home-finances-survey?",
         "updated_time": "2017-07-27T21:15:52+0000",
         "permalink_url": "https://www.facebook.com/groups/uwpartnersforum/permalink/1745120025791166/",
         "from": {
            "name": "John Oliver",
            "id": "10152744793754666"
         },
         "id": "1452979881671850_1745120025791166"
      },
      {
         "message": "We often think of communicating as figuring out a really good message and leaving it that. But the annoying fact is that unless we pay close attention to how that message is landing on the other person, not much communication will take place - Alan Alda",
         "updated_time": "2017-07-27T21:15:26+0000",
         "permalink_url": "https://www.facebook.com/groups/uwpartnersforum/permalink/1744867295816439/",
         "from": {
            "name": "Adrian Watts",
            "id": "10152461880942242"
         },
         "id": "1452979881671850_1744867295816439"
      }
   ]
}
```

and I am trying to extract, on comand prompt and in file, "message", "permalink_url", "updated_time", "name" and "id"(one inside from) post by a particular person, say "John Oliver". Following python script works.. mostly:

```
fhand = open('try1.json')
urlData = fhand.read()
jsonData = json.loads(urlData)
fout = open('output1.txt', 'w')
for i in jsonData["data"]:
    if i["from"]["name"] == "John Oliver":
        print (i["message"], end = "|")
        print (i["permalink_url"], end = "|")
        print (i["updated_time"], end = "|")
        print (i["from"]["name"], end = "|")
        print (i["from"]["id"], end = "\n")
        print()
        fout.write(str(i["message"]) + "|")
        fout.write(str(i["permalink_url"]) + "|")
        fout.write(str(i["updated_time"]) + "|")
        fout.write(str(i["from"]["name"]) + "|")
        fout.write(str(i["from"]["id"]) + "\n")
fout.close()
```

But I am facing two issues.
Issue 1. If there is no message in any records I am getting traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "facebook_feed.py", line 36, in <module>
    main()
  File "facebook_feed.py", line 25, in main
    print (i["message"], end = "|")
KeyError: 'message'
```

So, I need some help in going through the complete file even if there is no message for an object extracting all other details from it.

Issue 2. and this is a strange one ... I have two files "try1.json" with 500 odd records and "trial1.json" with 24000 odd records, with completely same structure. When I open "try1.json" in "Atom" text editor it is colour highlighted [smaller file in Atom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJIOP.jpg) but "trial1.json" is not colour highlighted [bigger file in atom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcR0k.jpg). On running the above script with try1.json, I am getting the KeyError for "message" (as shown above) but for "trial1.json" I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "facebook_feed.py", line 36, in <module>
    main()
  File "facebook_feed.py", line 20, in main
    if i["from"]["name"] == "John Oliver":
KeyError: 'from'
```

trial1.json is 17 MB file.. is that an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not sure if `i["message"]` exists, don't just blindly access it. Either use `dict.get`, e.g. `i.get('message', 'No message found')`, or check if it's there first:

```
if "message" in i:
    print (i["message"], end = "|")
```

You can do the same kind of thing with `i["from"]`.

Atom isn't highlighting the big file because it's big. But if you can successfully `json.loads` something, it's valid JSON.

Comment: Thank! That worked like a charm. I am new to programming and I tried a few variations of "if" but I was not accessing the dictionary elements in the right way with "message". With "from" I assumed that it is there for all records as on visually skimming through it, I couldn't find one without "from". Will keep these things in mind and try to learn things :) Once again, thanks.